# When $T$ is a Hausdorff topological space, what exactly is $C_0(T)$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

The question is as the title :

When $T$ is a Haudorff topological space, what exactly is $C_0(T)$?

It is said that when there is a measure $m$ on $T$, $L^p(T,m)$ is the completion of the space $C_0(T)$ with respect to the $L^p$-norm. I think $C_0(T)$ must be in some sense continuous functions 'vanishing in the infinity'. But how does one formulate this for arbitrary topological spaces?

Comment: Oh, yes the book I am reading uses $C_0$ for compactly supported ones....Thank you

Comment: I'd say the completion of the compactly supported continuous functions for the $\sup$ norm. Thus if $U_n\supset U_{n+1}$ is a sequence of subsets such that for all compact $\exists n,K\cap U_n= \emptyset$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x\in U_n}f(x)=0$. Moreover $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: The functions that can be continuously extended to the one-point compactification by setting $f(\infty) = 0$.